# Wordpress form sending

Tags: wordpress

I'm working on a problem with a wordpress-thing.

I have a gallery-like thing where you choose an option instead of an image, when you get into that option you choose you'll come to a text with a "mission" on it, under it there should be a form that you can fill in and send like "I want to get this mission" now I'm trying to figure out how that form can tell, in the mail sent; that it is that correct mission. Like how do I see in the mail that the person who sent it choose a specific "mission". It's kinda hard to understand, I send 2 images.

On image one you can see the "gallery"-like thing of mission-selecting

[image: Image 1]

On image 2 you'll see that you get into selected mission. From there it should be a form that you can attend that specific mission.

[image: Image 2]

So.. is there anyone who can lead me in the right direction here? The form who is sent from the specific "mission" should say something about that specific mission in the mail, so the receiver get what mission.

If you guys get what i mean and think i should solve it myself, could you atleast lead me on where i should work? is it in the php-send file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution could be to have an additional 'hidden' input field in your form.

When a user selects a mission, use JavaScript to set the mission information as the hidden forms value.

Then when the user submits the form, you should have all the info you need

I'm not sure if I fully understood the situation, but I hope this helps!

Comment: True! Amazing that i could explain this and get someone to understand. Im very Happy that you could help me. Thank you!